# Divide the bibliography in different sections

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, citing

I know it might be an easy solution but all the information I've found online are very fragmented and not clear.

I wrote a lot of pages for a project and at the end of the work I have different pages of citations. 
I would like to know if exist an easy way to divide this huge list in different sections. 
For example, I'd like to have one section with all the citations from the websites, one with the articles and books and one with the citations from the interviews.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: You might be interested in `biblatex`. See § 3.7.4, `Bibliography Sections`, § 3.7.5, `Bibliography Segments` and § 3.7.6, `Bibliography by Categories`, pp. 85–87 in the documentation.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Is there any easier solution? Also because some of these require to change all the citations, and I have around 500.